# Razor code in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a little problem.
I use asp.net mvc 5 and want to generate a 
DropdownlistFor by razor in javascript:

```
function addRowIndikator() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tb_1");
  var count = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(count - 2);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = "3";
  cell1.colSpan = 3;
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell3.innerHTML = @if(Model._LIndikator != null) {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._Indikator.Id, new SelectList(Model._LIndikator, "Id", "Name"), new {
      id = "selectIndi"
    })
  }
  else { <
    select >
      <
      option > Keine Indikatoren vorhanden < /option> <
      /select>
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work. Does someone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That's because you're generating HTML inside of JavaScript. Have you checked your Developer Tools in the browser?

Comment: Firebug doesn't know the razor code

Comment: It is about using Html inside js, nothing to do with razor. innerHTML expects a string. So your html must be inside a string.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane 
 
But you have the problem "only assignment-, call-, increment-, decrement- and new object-expression can be used as a statement"

Comment: yeah... i have updated my answer. this time i ran the code myself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is inside a .cshtml file, you need to make sure your html is set as a string. This means having them inside quotes. Regardless of if or not it is the razor code:

```
@{
    string innerHTML = Model._LIndikator != null ? 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._Indikator.Id, new SelectList(Model._LIndikator, "Id", "Name"), new {id = "selectIndi"}).ToString()
        : "<select><option>Keine Indikatoren vorhanden</option></select>";
} 

        cell3.innerHTML = "@Html.Raw(innerHTML)";
```

In this way you have first created a string variable that stores your html. Then you take care of the special characters by using `Html.Raw`.

You can always use helpers if it you plan on this too often.

Comment: But you have the problem "only assignment-, call-, increment-, decrement- and new object-expression can be used as a statement"

Comment: noted. I just answered without testing the code first. This one is tested